# Error: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid when Deploy on Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, visualstudiocode, session-id

I found some public question which treat this topic, but I didn't get a specific solution.

I have this error message when I try to deploy my files from local to my org.

```
Error: INVALID_SESSION_ID: Session expired or invalid
```

It's the first time it happens. I have opened session on this org but I cannot deploy files from local. I tried to do the solution using this command on terminal:

```
lsof -i tcp:1717
```

But it does not work.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried authorizing again with the Salesforce extension in VS Code? https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/development-models

Comment: I've been getting this as well for the last couple of weeks.  Since Spring 21 landed - not sure if related.  I have to Authorize Org every time I see this error message.

Comment: Please check this issue link https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/890#issuecomment-790062421 and https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-core/pull/380/commits/5bcabcf727ad9e4306c3e1a2ed4825e60115f939

Comment: Thank all of you guys. I solved the problem deleting alias associated with the org, and then, I rewrite the alias. It worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this issue after I had to change my password in the sandbox. I just ran this command to fix it:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -a <alias> -d -r https://test.salesforce.com
```

This will open up your browser to login to the sandbox. I was able to deploy to the org after doing this.

(The -r lets you login to a sandbox. Without it, your browser will open to login.salesforce.com.)

Comment: Just today I had same problem on another deployment and it worked! Thank you dazmae!

Comment: Thanks - this resolved my issue. Although i didn't have to change my password.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it through the following steps-

At the bottom left of your VS Code you will find a small box icon to 'open the org'[image]. Just click on that. Wait till the operation finishes. Then try to deploy again.

Comment: Or `sfdx force:org:open` or `Command-P SFDX: Open Default Org` but the real question is why ANY of it is necessary when we have a valid auth token already registered.  Why does `open` work but not `push`?

Answer (score -1):

In case you're deploying to a scratch org, executing sfdx force:org:list in your terminal should refresh your connections - see thread [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IZK5QAO)

After this command finishes, try deploying again and it should work.

Comment: `sfdx force:org:open` works to renew the session, but not list.

Comment: Have you tried it? I did and it worked for me

Comment: I did, and it didn't refresh the token for whatever reason.

Comment: Are you working against a scratch org or a sandbox? This trick worked only for scratch orgs. Could be that after some version it stopped working.
However, things moved since then and it's been acknowledged as a platform issue and the most up to date recommendation is to follow the github issue for updates:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/899

Comment: Gotcha, if you edit the answer to make that more explicit I can remove my downvote.